# What are the differences between "all year / day / month.." & "all the year / day / month..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

We often hear:

**I have been working hard all year / day / month**

When should we say this sentence?

Say at the end of 2017, I say: **I have been working hard all year**

Does it mean: **I have been working hard for the whole 2017**?

When should we say: **I have been working hard all the year**?

What are the differences between "**all year / day / month...**" & "**all the year / day / month...**"?

Comment: Most native speakers would rarely if ever include the (syntactically, *optional*) article ***the*** in such contexts (or indeed, ***of the***). I could contrive contexts where it might even be *preferable* to include *[**of**] **the***, but they really would be contrived. And it would always be perfectly okay *not* to include it between ***all + day / month / year***, so I suggest just do that every time.

Comment: There's [*All Day And All **Of The** Night*](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kinks/alldayandallofthenight.html) by The Kinks, but that's just because they needed more syllables to match the song's tempo.